# Google PageSpeed score and css file included within ajax rendered html

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I have website and some html is loaded with ajax call (dynamic blocks). Within the ajax included html block is also dynamic css. It includes different css files based on different conditions. Ajax call takes around 3 seconds, sometimes 5s (because block can be set to be displayed with some delay by purpose). Now Google PageSpeed is showing bad score showing there is 3-5s delay for css files while actual loading time is just 100ms.

I include css within ajax called template like this:

```
jQuery('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.example.com/" . $cssVersion . ".css" type="text/css" />'
```

Is there some attribute I could add or something to prevent bad score because of this?

Comment: Have you inlined your critical CSS, are you sure that there is no critical 'above the fold' CSS within that file?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the CSS file you are loading only includes rules relevant to the Ajax loaded html.

Also try using an intersection observer to load the html when the page is about to display the content rather than running at page load.

Additionally, if you can eliminate the jQuery dependency you’ll do yourself a big favor.